# Enum as java.wx.rs.DefaultValue

Tags: java, rest, enums

I'd like to provide an enum value as DefaultValue in a header parameter. But `@DefaultValue` only accepts compile time constant strings, not enums. Here's a minimal working example:

```java
    package com.my.package;

    import javax.ws.rs.DefaultValue;
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;

    @Path("/some_path")
    public class TestService {
        public enum MyEnum{
            FOO,
            BAR;
        }

        @GET
        public String defaultAsHardcodedString(@HeaderParam("x-my-header") @DefaultValue("FOO")  MyEnum myEnum) {
            // compiles but i don't like it because most benefits of using an enum are gone
            return "unimportant";
        }

        @GET
        public String defaultAsDynamicString(@HeaderParam("x-my-header") @DefaultValue(MyEnum.FOO.toString()) MyEnum myEnum) {
            // compile error "The value for annotation attribute DefaultValue.value must be a constant expressionJava(536871525)"
            return "unimportant";
        }

        @GET
        public String defaultAsEnum(@HeaderParam("x-my-header") @DefaultValue(MyEnum.FOO) MyEnum myEnum) {
            // compile error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyEnum to StringJava(16777233)"
            return "unimportant";
        }
    }
```

The compile errors say:

> The value for annotation attribute DefaultValue.value must be a constant expression

if I try to use `@DefaultValue(MyEnum.Foo.toString())` or

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyEnum to String

for `@DefaultValue(MyEnum.Foo)` respectivly.

Comment: can you try MyEnum.FOO.name()

Comment: @dassum : same result as with the `toString()` method: "The value for annotation attribute DefaultValue.value must be a constant expressionJava(536871525)"

Comment: Well, you can't. There's no way around it. Your must pass a String since that's what the type of the attribute is, and it must be a compile-time constant. DOn't use an enum for these default values. use two String constants.

Comment: Cannot you define a constant like `private final String DEFAULT_VALUE = MyEnum.FOO.name()` and use that constant?